# how to get rid of warnings from using find

Tags: command-line, find

I got lots of warnings when I search a certain file under a directory with lots of dangling links.
I tried to use the -nowarn option to get rid of the warnings but in vain. The warnings
I get look like:

```
find: ./foo/bar: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you specify which operating system's version of find you are using, and give the exact command line.  I tried a simple example and didn't get any warnings for dangling symlinks.

Comment: I guess you are not using the command correctly, but you really have to give further information for something helpful.

Comment: As well as the OS/find versions, specifying the command lines you have tried would be helpful. Some sample output from these commands and `ls -l` for the directory in question may also help. Detailed questions make it easier for respondents to give relevant answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` like these examples:

```
find . -type f 2> /dev/null
find . -type f -print0 2> /dev/null | xargs -0 ls -l
```

though the concern here would be that you are ignoring *all* errors reported on stderr by `find`, so removing the dangling symlinks if they are not needed <sup><sub>(they might be required if they refer to filesystems that are not mounted right now but will be later, for instance, but if there is not reason for them to be present then get rid of them rather than trying to hide warnings about them)</sub></sup> would be the first choice of solution.

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the warnings (i.e not fixing them) this should be enough